# How to correctly write and read PNGs to database as BLOB with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, base64, png

I am trying to upload some PNG files to a database as BLOBs, then displaying them on a webpage, using PHP. The files are ~1MB PNGs, 1024*1024px.

Here's my insertion code:

```
$file = addslashes(file_get_contents('myimage.png'));
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','mydb');
if (!$mysqli) die("Can't connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error());
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `mydb`.`Image` (`id`,`value`) VALUES(null, ?);');
$null = NULL;
$stmt->bind_param("b", $null);
$stmt->send_long_data(0, $file);
$stmt->execute();
```

In the database the blob values appear.

I'm trying to use them like this:

```
<div style="background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,<?php echo base64_encode(mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT value FROM Image WHERE id=4;'))[0]); ?>)"></div>
```

In the HTML output it appears to be a valid base64 string, but all my browsers say "The image (base64 string) cannot be displayed because it contains errors.

Where's the error in my code? Any better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why you bind a null value?

Comment: Why don't you save the image in a directory and store the file name in the database?

Comment: @Jerson that's for the send_long_data :)

Comment: @Baracuda078 I don't want the users to be able to see a directory or filename in the output.

Comment: Why? You always need to rename files with a random generated string and your .htaccess needs to be configured correct so directories can not be opened in the browser. You make it your self extra hard and your database will get huge in a short time and your sever needs to convert every time the images when it gets requested.